# Error 8007017c using CfCreatePlaceholders after Windows update KB4592449

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm using the Cloud Mirror [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-classic-samples/cloudmirror-sample/) and I could create placeholders correctly before the Windows Update [KB4592449](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4592449/windows-10-update-kb4592449). But after this update I can't create placeholders for the second or higher folder level in the base directory path, using the [CfCreatePlaceholders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/nf-cfapi-cfcreateplaceholders) function as is used in the [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-classic-samples/cloudmirror-sample/), the error code 8007017c is now launched by this function. I reviewed this Spanish [article](https://www.spanishnewsnow.com/actualizaciones-acumulativas-de-windows-10-kb4592449-y-kb4592438-publicadas/) where is mentioned that with the 18362.1256 and 18363.1256 Operating System compilations is avoided the security vulnerability that the apps that are executed as a SYSTEM account can print in the "FILE:" ports. And there is a suggestion that says: make sure your apps and services are executed as a specific user or service account. Currently I tried to execute my app as another account using [PsExec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) and [Process Hacker](https://processhacker.sourceforge.io/) tools but I couldn't execute my app using a different account and I'm not really sure that with this my problem will be solved. If anyone could help me I will appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: I think you're running into this: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/issues/164

Comment: Yes [Raymond Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902497/raymond-chen), that is my current problem, thanks for the link, meanwhile I will try the workaround that Hannah von Reth mentioned in her comment. Where will the Cloud Mirror team post the update when this issue has been solved?

Comment: The solution is to make sure that the RelativeFileName is *just* the filename, not a relative path. This was a bug in the sample. I do not have a timeline for the fix.

Comment: Thank you so much [Raymond Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902497/raymond-chen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce this issue on OS Build 19042.685.

The following is an example workaround (temporarily) you can refer to:

Change these code lines of [CloudMirror](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/5d152f51dc5b3ce3d1bb50e7435496fe7b080887/Samples/CloudMirror/CloudMirror/Placeholders.cpp#L73):

```
    std::wstring relativeName(sourceSubDir); 
    relativeName.append(findData.cFileName);
```

To

```
    std::wstring relativeName(findData.cFileName); // relativeName is just the file name

    std::wstring destDir(destPath);
    destDir.append(L"\\");
    destDir.append(sourceSubDir); // destPath is complete directory of the file including the subfolder under root directory

    // ...

    winrt::check_hresult(CfCreatePlaceholders(destDir.data(), &cloudEntry, 1, CF_CREATE_FLAG_NONE, NULL));
```

Comment: Hello [Rita Han - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6601582/rita-han-msft), as was written on this [post](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/issues/164) and as you posted in your answer a workaround for this problem is using the complete directory where the file is, as the BaseDirectoryPath parameter in the CfCreatePlaceholders function, and the RelativeFileName and FileIdentity attributes in the CF_PLACEHOLDER_CREATE_INFO structure must be only the filename. Thanks for your answer.